# How to fix memory leak in Word Add-In

Tags: c#, wpf, memory-leaks, ms-word, vsto

I have a MS Word Application Add-in written with VSTO. It contains a button used to create new Letter documents. When pressed a document is instantiated, a WPF dialog is displayed to capture information and then the information is inserted into the document.

On one of my test machines I get the following exception when approximately 40 letters are created in a single Word session:

> The disk is full. Free some space on this drive, or save the document
>   on another disk.
>
> Try one or more of the following:
>
> - Close any unneeded documents, programs or windows.
> - Save the document to another disk.

So I monitored the Winword.exe process using Task Manager:

- Memory starts at 97,000k
- Memory steadily increases with each letter document until the error is seen at approximately 1,000,000k
- If I then close all the documents the memory only drops down to 500,000k

Any tips on how I can troubleshoot the memory leak?
I've gone through my code and ensured that event handlers are unregistered and that i'm disposing objects that need disposing.
Any reference articles that I should be reading?

-- Edit --
Malick, I use unmanaged code to make the WPF window look like an Office dialog. Is there a better way of doing this? I'll try removing it. (edit, there wasn't a change. I'll try the memory monitoring tools)

```
public class OfficeDialog : Window
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hwnd, int index);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hwnd, int index, int newStyle);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr hwndInsertAfter, int x, int y, int width, int height, uint flags);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, uint msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    const int GWL_EXSTYLE = -20;
    const int WS_EX_DLGMODALFRAME = 0x0001;
    const int SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
    const int SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;
    const int SWP_NOZORDER = 0x0004;
    const int SWP_FRAMECHANGED = 0x0020;
    const uint WM_SETICON = 0x0080;
    const int ICON_SMALL = 0;
    const int ICON_BIG = 1;

    public OfficeDialog()
    {
        this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        //this.Topmost = true;
    }

    public new void ShowDialog()
    {
        try
        {
            var helper = new WindowInteropHelper(this);
            using (Process currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
                helper.Owner = currentProcess.MainWindowHandle;
            base.ShowDialog();
        }
        catch (System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception ex)
        {
            Message.LogWarning(ex);
            //this.Topmost = true;
            var helper = new WindowInteropHelper(this);
            using (Process currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
                helper.Owner = currentProcess.MainWindowHandle;
            base.ShowDialog();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSourceInitialized(e);
        RemoveIcon(this);
        HideMinimizeAndMaximizeButtons(this);
        //using (Process currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
        //    SetCentering(this, currentProcess.MainWindowHandle);
    }

    public static void HideMinimizeAndMaximizeButtons(Window window)
    {
        const int GWL_STYLE = -16;

        IntPtr hwnd = new WindowInteropHelper(window).Handle;
        long value = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE);

        SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, (int)(value & -131073 & -65537));
    }

    public static void RemoveIcon(Window w)
    {
        // Get this window's handle 
        IntPtr hwnd = new WindowInteropHelper(w).Handle;

        // Change the extended window style to not show a window icon
        int extendedStyle = OfficeDialog.GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE);
        OfficeDialog.SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, extendedStyle | WS_EX_DLGMODALFRAME);

        // reset the icon, both calls important
        OfficeDialog.SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SETICON, (IntPtr)ICON_SMALL, IntPtr.Zero);
        OfficeDialog.SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SETICON, (IntPtr)ICON_BIG, IntPtr.Zero);

        // Update the window's non-client area to reflect the changes
        OfficeDialog.SetWindowPos(hwnd, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_FRAMECHANGED);
    }

    static void SetCentering(Window win, IntPtr ownerHandle)
    {
        bool isWindow = IsWindow(ownerHandle);
        if (!isWindow) //Don't try and centre the window if the ownerHandle is invalid.  To resolve issue with invalid window handle error
        {
            //Message.LogInfo(string.Format("ownerHandle IsWindow: {0}", isWindow));
            return;
        }
        //Show in center of owner if win form.
        if (ownerHandle.ToInt32() != 0)
        {
            var helper = new WindowInteropHelper(win);
            helper.Owner = ownerHandle;
            win.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;
        }
        else
            win.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool IsWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
```

}

Comment: What version of VS are you using? Can you run the Diagnostic Tools? See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt210448.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: did you call some unmanaged code ?

Comment: you could try something like ANTS (just to name one). There is a 14 days test version available. You can see which (managed) objects are causing high memory. http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/ I don't know if it's working with office addins

Comment: I'll try removing my unmanaged code and then use one of the diagnostic tools.